# Rspec - using .attributes to dry up lets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have two instances, the only difference between them is one value (complete) I was hoping to use something like this but it doesn't work:

```
let(:section){Section.new(:date => '2015-05-01', :task_id => 1, :trade_id => 1, :schedule_id => 1)}
let(:complete_section){Section.new(section.attributes, complete: true)}
```

When I do that, the attributes get set from `section.attributes`, however `complete: true` is ignored.

Is there another way I can grab the attributes from the base :section so I don't need to write all the attributes every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does

```
let(:complete_section){Section.new(section.attributes.merge(complete: true))}
```

do what you want?

Comment: Yes it does! Is this new for Rspec 3?  I'll flag as answered when the time limit is off.

Comment: `merge` is just plain Ruby, this isn't an RSpec feature.

Comment: Yep as @AndyWaite said, this is just plain old Ruby.. attributes is just a hash, so we can just merge complete in.   I would also agree with Andy and if I was doing this I would use Factory Girl (but I would also use traits.  so I would have things like :section, :completed_section, etc..  that I could call when needed

Answer (score 1):

A common solution to this problem is [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl), where you can define a template and just override the necessary values:

```
let(:section) { FactoryGirl.build(:section) }
let(:complete_section) { FactoryGirl.build(:section, complete: true}
```